# WordPress Theme modification to swap logos in header

Tags: css, wordpress, header, graphical-logo

On this site: http://new.thebeatfitness.net/ I'm using a child theme of this theme: https://organicthemes.com/demo/startup/ In the theme it has two headers built in, one for light backgrounds and one for dark. The theme has the navigation swapping light and dark but not the logo. Seems stupid but when I asked the theme developers they said it was built that way.

Can anyone guide me as to how to have the theme also swap logos based on background in addition to text nav?

Comment: In this case, you can use two logos(with two different colors) matching with header background colors.

Comment: That's obvious about the two different color logos. My question is how to get the THEME to PULL IN the different logos BASED ON THE BACKGROUND like it does for navigation.

Answer (score 2):

Basically speaking, your theme toggles a class when you scroll.

This:

```
<div id="nav-bar" class="dark">
```

Becomes this:

```
<div id="nav-bar" class="light">
```

Your logo is loaded through an `img` element in html. The easiest option at your disposal is instead to load the logo via css.

```
.dark .site-logo a{ background: url('http://new.thebeatfitness.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/beat-silver-logo_dark.png'); }
.light .site-logo a{ background: url('http://new.thebeatfitness.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/beat-silver-logo_light.png'); }
```

The original theme you're modifying is actually using one image for both cases. Instead they change the text color, which is easier.

Comment: I tried that, I even added a z-index but it doesn't display any logo unless I add it within the theme options panel.

Comment: @CreativEliza try it again and I could take a look at your live example. You must be doing something wrong.

Comment: In the header the code is this from the original theme:
   <!-- BEGIN .site-logo -->
   <div class="site-logo">

    <?php the_custom_logo(); ?>

    <?php if ( is_front_page() && is_home() || is_front_page() ) { ?>
     <h1 class="site-title">
      <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php echo wp_kses_post( get_bloginfo( 'name' ) ); ?></a>
     </h1>
    <?php } else { ?>

I think I'm missing how to call the logo into the theme.

Comment: I don't see you setting background image anywhere in `css`.

Comment: I don't know how to call the background into the theme. I showed you above the code for calling in the logo which is added in the customizer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158529/discussion-between-creativeliza-and-serg-chernata).